# Timer Tick event suddenly not working

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, events, timer

Yesterday I was working on a project and using a timer. Today I went to the same project and the timer no longer works! I thought it may be a logic error (no syntax or runtime errors reported) but I do not know what is going on. The timer's interval is set to 2000, it's called when a button is clicked, and is supposed to show a messagebox. It's not working and I'm going out of my mind!

The snippet of code that handles the timer is here:

```
    private void buttonFindColor_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // start the timer
        timerMain.Start();
    }

    private void timerMain_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("I ticked!");

        timerMain.Stop();
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a chance the Tick event is not "wired" to the timer.

Does this line exist anywhere?

```
timerMain.Tick += timerMain_Tick;
```

Comment: No, it doesn't. Does it matter where it is placed?

Comment: Put it in the constructor or wherever timerMain is created, then you are sure the event will be wired up.

Comment: I would put it with the `timerMain`'s instantiation.

Comment: usually it's in the   private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            this.components = new System.ComponentModel.Container();
            this.timer1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer(this.components);
            this.SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // timer1
            // 
            this.timer1.Tick += new System.EventHandler(this.timer1_Tick);
            //